Siglent vs Tek vs keysight
I am looking for a D.S.O. for my company for power electronics application. Our product is induction furnace in range of power 25kW to 500 kW, 100khz to 1 Mhz frequency. Our use of DSO is also for pcb development and testing. Which brand provides higher reliability and which excels in which feature compared to it's counterparts. I have explored siglent SDS2000 series which is cheap and provides more features compared to it's counterparts like touch screen, bigger screen , mouse and keyboard access, more marh functions etc. compared to keysight and tektronix.
Is it advisable to go for siglent or are there better alternatives in keysight or tek?
Sorry I can't find suitable tags for this and I can't create a new specific tag so went with the most suitable i found. Please suggest me if there is more specific tag for this question.
